Cursor pagination - do people purposely create a sequential column if their primary key is not?
I am curious if its common practice to purposefully create a sequential column like indice if you know you'll be using cursor pagination, especially if you don't have one as a primary key (UUID, etc)? I realize you can use createdAt column, but from experience, especially with seeding, sometimes there are two items with the same timestamp.
